# How to fix 'onClick to show content'?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have simple side navigation on my webpage, and have little problem i think with javascript code. What i need? When user open that page and choose to see content from category of 'Audi' to show sub-category in this case to show ( audi a4 and audi a5). Now is set to opened so user don't need to click on category 'Audi' to see content.

```
<h4>Side navigation</h4>
<nav class="checklist side-nav-toggle ajax">
    <h5><a href="#" class="opened">Audi</h5>

    <ul class="scroll-list" style="display:block;">
      <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Audi A3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Audi A5</a></li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: what kind of problem have you got, exactly? Where's your code? What part of your code isn't working?

Comment: I have write my code. What i need? When click on 'Audi' to display content below 'Audi a5 and audi a3'. Now i don't need to click on 'Audi' to display content because content is already displayed. And i don't need that, i need to add javascript function onClick to show that content. @ADyson

Comment: My english is so bad, but i need to create next, when user click on Audi then show content of Audi A3 and Audi A5 and when click again to hide that content. @ADyson

Comment: If you've got a problem with your JavaScript code, you need to add it to your question. However, if you are asking us to write the JavaScript code for you, then I must inform you that StackOverflow isn't here to write the code for you and your question might be deemed as off topic. We can help debug and rewrite the code, but you must have shown you've done a bit of research and tried some code yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Sidebar Dropdown code example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_dropdown), hope this helps you.

Using bootstrap you can save a lot of time on these things.

For tag `<a>` use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown#)

Comment: I don't have button i need to do that in <a href="">Audi</a>

Comment: try the example 2 with links

Answer (score 0):

You should use Audi as parent item and if you add children items, you should add `display:none;` to css code of children item. After that, you can use javascript or jquery for click events.

```js
$(function(){
$(".has-child-title").click(function(){
$(this).next("ul").toggle();
});
});
```

```css
  .children{
    display:none;
    }
    li{
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    *{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
  
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h4>Side navigation</h4>
    <nav class="checklist side-nav-toggle ajax">
    <ul>
    <li class="has-child">
      <h5 class="has-child-title"><a>Audi</a></h5>
      <ul class="children scroll-list">
      <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Audi A3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Audi A5</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
    <h5><a>Mercedes</a></h5>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h4>Side navigation</h4>
    <nav class="checklist side-nav-toggle ajax">
        <h5><a href="#" class="opened">Audi</h5>

        <ul class="scroll-list" style="display:block;">
          <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Audi A3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Audi A5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

General problem is in `<ul class="scrill-list" style="display: block;">` if we remove `style="display: block;`then we will get closed our navigation but if we leave this line of code, our navigation will be opened on page load.